# how to get table structre of a database in java?

Tags: java, jdbc, table-structure

how to get table structre of a database in java?

Comment: You need to add context and additional detail to this question. As-is, it's not possible to answer.

Comment: Actually i want to take backup of sql database. please help in this regard.i-e what will be algorithm,or steps involve to do so?

Comment: You could use SHOW TABLES, then each result will have a line containing table name. Use SHOW CREATE TABLE <table_name> to get table creation code.

Answer (score 13):

Use [DatabaseMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) to get the table information.

You can use the `getTablexxx()` and `getColumnxx()` methods to get the table information.

```
Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(.....);
DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
dbmd.getxxxx();
```

Comment: And there is ResultSetMetaData: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html

Comment: +1. This is the official interface, but it is a terrible one. It returns ResultSets that you have to parse. They could have thrown in some proper interfaces for these data structures in one of the JDBC revs.

Answer (score -1):

If you just care about being able to recreate the table on a different server, you can use `SHOW TABLES` to get a list of tables, then `SHOW CREATE TABLE foo` to get the `CREATE TABLE` command.  You might also look at the mysqldump program to see if it better suits your needs.

Joshua

Answer (score -2):

One way is to use [hibernate](http://hibernate.org), reverse engineer and generate entity beans according to your existing database.