# Java ResultSet - get Column name based on Index

Tags: java, jdbc

I want to know if there is a way to get a column name based on the index from a resultSet.

I know that if you want to get index based on the columnName, you can do that by using

```
int index = resultSet.findColumn(columnName);
```

But I need the other way around, something like :

```
String column = resultSet.findColumnName(index);
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I think you need to look at [`ResultSet.getMetaData()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getMetaData%28%29) which returns the meta-data associated with a `ResultSet`.

You can then iterate over the columns (use [`getColumnCount()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnCount%28%29) to find out how many there are) to find the column with the given name, checking with [`getColumnName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName%28int%29). Don't forget that column indexes are 1-based, rather than 0-based. Something like:

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();

int count = metaData.getColumnCount();
for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
{
    if (metaData.getColumnName(i).equals(desiredColumnName))
    {
        // Whatever you want to do here.
    }
}
```

If you need to do this for a lot of names, you may want to build a `HashMap<String, Integer>` to map them easily.

Answer (score 7):

Of course - use [java.sql.ResultSetMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html).

```
ResultSetMetaData meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
String column = meta.getColumnName(index);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

With standard JDBC, you can get the result set's [metadata](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html):

```
ResultSetMetaData metadata = resultSet.getMetaData()
```

This object can then be queried for the column name (by index):

```
String columnFiveName = metadata.getColumnName(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

How about [`ResultSetMetaData`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) 's[`getColumnName()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnName%28int%29) ?

---

**For Example:**

```
ResultSetMetaData metaData = resultSet.getMetaData()
metaData.getColumnName(1) ;
```

---

**See Also**

- [how-to-get-table-structre-of-a-database-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4449437/how-to-get-table-structre-of-a-database-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this using [ResultSetMetaData](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html):

```
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = resultSet.getMetaData();
String column = rsmd.getColumnName(index);
```